# case_when() erratic behaviour

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, case-when

I'm trying to run a case_when inside a mutate, and get the following errors.

```
Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env)
```

Or

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
    "        )
    df"
```

Or

```
> modelo == "Onix (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Onix (2013)",
Error: unexpected ',' in "modelo == "Onix (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Onix (2013)","
>         modelo == "Chevrolet Cruze (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Cruze (2013)",
Error: unexpected ',' in "        modelo == "Chevrolet Cruze (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Cruze (2013)","
>         TRUE ~ modelo)) %>%
Error: unexpected ')' in "        TRUE ~ modelo)"
>     dplyr::mutate(modelo_alternativo = dplyr::case_when(
+
```

My code is the following:

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(modelo = dplyr::case_when(
        modelo == "Onix (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Onix (2013)",
        modelo == "Chevrolet Cruze (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Cruze (2013)",
        TRUE ~ modelo)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(modelo_alternativo = dplyr::case_when(
        modelo_alternativo == "Chevrolet Onix (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Onix (2013)",
        modelo_alternativo == "Chevrolet Cruze (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Cruze (2013)",
        modelo_alternativo == "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Prisma (2013)",
        TRUE ~ modelo_alternativo))
```

And sometimes when I change it to this, it runs OK:

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(modelo = dplyr::case_when(
        modelo == "Onix (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Onix (2013)",
        modelo == "Chevrolet Cruze (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Cruze (2013)",
        TRUE ~ modelo)
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(modelo_alternativo = dplyr::case_when(
        modelo_alternativo == "Chevrolet Onix (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Onix (2013)",
        modelo_alternativo == "Chevrolet Cruze (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Cruze (2013)",
        modelo_alternativo == "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)" ~ "CHEVROLET Prisma (2013)",
        TRUE ~ modelo_alternativo)
    )
```

I checked the syntax like 1000 times, column classes are OK, and read answer about case_when() issues. I need this to work stably and really what to code these replacements without risk of getting stuck.

Do you have any clue on what is happening here?

The packages I load are:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(foreign)
library(here)
library(dplyr)
```

Data for reprex:

```
df <- structure(list(modelo = c("CHEVROLET Sonic (2012)", "CHEVROLET Sonic (2012)", 
                          "CHEVROLET S10 (2012)", "CHEVROLET Sonic (2012)", "CHEVROLET Classic (2010)", 
                          "CHEVROLET Sonic (2012)", "CHEVROLET S10 (2012)", "CHEVROLET S10 (2012)", 
                          "CHEVROLET S10 (2012)", "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", 
                          "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", 
                          "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", 
                          "Chevrolet Prisma (2013)", "CHEVROLET S10 (2012)", "Onix (2013)"
), modelo_alternativo = c("VOLKSWAGEN Suran (2015)", "TOYOTA Corolla (2014)", 
                          "TOYOTA Hilux (ARG 2012)", "TOYOTA Corolla (2014)", "VOLKSWAGEN Gol Trend (2012)", 
                          "RENAULT Sandero Stepway (2015)", "FORD Ranger (2012)", "RENAULT FLUENCE (2015)", 
                          "FORD Ranger (2012)", "CHEVROLET Agile (ARG 2009)", "Toyota Etios", 
                          "Chevrolet Onix (2013)", NA, "Peugeot 208", "VOLKSWAGEN Suran (2015)", 
                          "VOLKSWAGEN Voyage (2012)", "CHEVROLET Spin (2012)", "CHEVROLET Cobalt", 
                          "TOYOTA Hilux (ARG 2012)", "FORD EcoSport (2012)")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                             20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I didn't get any error using your data and rerunning your code. What is the difference between the two code chunks you provided? And is this exactly the same code that produced the error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, everything runs as expected and both code examples return `identical()` results. Sometimes the error comes from a mismatched parenthesis somewhere, are you using a syntax aware editor or IDE?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The difference is an extra line in mutate's closing parenthesis. I am using RStudio, it highlights syntax issues, but it doesn't detect any issue in the code I shared.

Comment: Does this work as expected for you on sample data shared? As others have already pointed out this works fine for us with both the code without any error.

Comment: When you ctrl+enter code in RStudio, it runs any unfinished line in the previous chunk. Writing `x=1` just the line before `df <- ...` would prevent this from happening, else copy-pasting to the console should do. Even best is to correct the previous lines if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I think I found the issue. While coding I usually write at the end of the sentence and modify things. Just retry my example, and when I do Ctrl. + Enter from the end of the sentence (i. e. after `TRUE ~ modelo_alternativo))` it crashes. I understand that it doesn't recognise the line begins at `df %>%  ...`. Is this supposed to happen? Not sure is a bad habit of mine or an IDE issue. Thank you!